# How to download Riak TS package from Zendesk

Tags: riak, zendesk

I am trying to install riak-ts version 1.0.0 and on [this page](http://docs.basho.com/riakts/latest/installing/debian-ubuntu/). They mention download package is available from ZenDesk, but in zendesk site I did not find such link.

Answer (score 1):

ZenDesk is a customer support site.  If Basho has put files there, you will likely need to get an account from them in order to log in download them.

Answer (score 1):

Riak TS is currently (as the time of answer) only available to Riak enterprise customers and they can download its package from their ZenDesk panel.

Answer (score 1):

Update (Oct 2016)
Riak TS has been open sourced since that time. The download packages are at [http://docs.basho.com/riak/ts/latest/downloads/](http://docs.basho.com/riak/ts/1.4.0/downloads/).